# Getting INVALID_REQUEST_BODY error on accessing create_template_view api

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to access the api  `TemplateViews : createEdit` using python docusign_esign api as below

```
api_client = ApiClient(header_name="Authorization", header_value=f"Bearer {access_token}",
                           host="https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/")
TemplatesApi(api_client).create_edit_view(account_id=account_id, template_id=template_id)
```

while accessing the create_edit_view I am getting the error as

```
"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"The request body is missing or improperly formatted."
```

when checked in the API explorer, I am able to get the response URL correctly. I found only the accountId and templateId is mandatory for accessing the api, am I missing something else here?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools/python/reference/docusign_esign/apis/templates_api.html#docusign_esign.apis.templates_api.TemplatesApi.create_edit_view

You need to provide a `return_url`, it's a URL that your embedded sender will be redirected back to when they finished editing/creating the template.

This is a POST and this URL is provided in the body as JSON, not in the URL as a parameter.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/templates/templateviews/createedit/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got your point but I don't want to redirect the user to any other page, since I am rendering this response URL in an Iframe. when I checked in the API Explorer/Postman I am able to get the URL without passing any redirect_url. Is is possible with the python sdk to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I'm a little confused that you were able to do that without a return_url. Can you share the API logs?